How do I run a Kedro pipeline on a particular input csv dataset that contains a list of requests that have to be evaluated
My main input is a list of checks (in a csv file) that I have to evaluate on a huge dataset.
In my main node, I parse the csv file, and for each row, I get the corresponding data from the catalog, extract the data, conduct my analysis and finally, if I have 5 rows in my input csv file, I append all 5 outputs (which is a lot of rows) vertically on top of each other (because the number of datasets my pipeline returns depends on the number of rows in the input csv file, and in Kedro you can only return a specified number of datasets, also looking for ways to optimize this)
How do I pass the data in such a way that I can run my pipeline how a conventional Kedro pipeline is supposed to be run (data flowing from one node to another, instead of using 1 node to call multiple functions due to my input being in a csv file).
Now, I can only evaluate one check at a time, and I need to expand this to make sure multiple checks (or multiple rows in my input csv) can be evaluated simultaneously, based on grouping some input parameters.
I am writing in PySpark, and I am very new to pipelines and python so any help will be appreciated.

To help you, I need to clarify a few details.:

Can you share some pseudo code? Could you provide a brief example of the code you have so far.
Can you share a sample of your CSV dataset or scheme? It would be helpful if you could provide a small snippet (2-3 rows) of your CSV file. This will give me a better understanding of the structure of your data.
Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to evaluate multiple checks in parallel? How do you want the data to flow through the nodes in your pipeline?

